# pgrep -f from shell script is returning 2 pid instead of 1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, unix, shell

**code :**

```
function main {
  
    [ -z "$@" ] && { getProcessId "$@" } || "$@"
}


getProcessId(){

matchType=$1
#defaulting matchArg to x i.e exact match
matchArg=x
processName=$2

if [[ $matchType == 'contains' ]];then
  matchArg=f
elif [[ $matchType == 'exact' ]];then
  matchArg=x
fi

if processId=`pgrep -$matchArg $processName`
then
echo "process id fetch is successful" 
else
 echo "process id fetched is blank" 
fi

echo "$processId"

}


main "$@"
```

**command use to run the script -** ./a.sh getProcessId contains ServiceResilience

it returns 2 pids instead of 1
and if i run directly on cmd as :**pgrep -f ServiceResilience** it returns only 1 pid (excepted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two PIDs that the script returns are the PID of the process interpreting the script (which contains ServiceResilience in its command line) and the PID of `pgrep` (which also contains ServiceResilience in its command line). If run directly in a terminal window, the script is not being run and so there is only one program. `pgrep`, with that in its command line.

Comment: thanks for the comment . but how we can fix this from script  as it was working earlier but now not sure what went wrong that now it is returning 2 pid instead of 1.

Comment: Something must have changed for it to have changed behavior. In particular look at how `pgrep` is being invoked - is a new command shell being launched to execute that operation?

Comment: if i am passing value from variable for processName its woking if i am taking processName from argument i.e $2 its not working

Comment: As posted your script throws multiple errors in `bash`; I can't diagnose it further. Are you using some other shell? But with the name hard-coded in the script, it is no longer on the command line for script invocation, so the script invocation doesn't match the condition. You're probably going to have to get creative with the conditionals to ignore specifically the script invocation instance and optionally the pgrep instance, to make this work.

Comment: `pgrep` is specifically coded to never return its own PID (and similarly `pkill` never kills itself). If run from a script which is given the commandname as an argument, _and_ it uses `-f` as this Q apparently does, it will indeed return the PID of (the shell running) the script.

Comment: So perhaps there really is a process that `pgrep` is picking up, with the value `ServiceResilience` on its command line. The extra is clearly still the script interpreter shell.