# argument to pgrep from cmdline returns 2 PID's and argument from global variable value returns 1 PID

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, unix, shell

1.first case(processName as argument from cmd i.e java)

command from cmd with arguments : ./a.sh getProcessId contains java

code:

```
getProcessId(){

matchType=$1
#defaulting matchArg to x i.e exact match
matchArg=x
processName=$2

if [[ $matchType == 'contains' ]];then
  matchArg=f
elif [[ $matchType == 'exact' ]];then
  matchArg=x
fi

if processId=`pgrep -$matchArg $processName`
then
 log $selectedLogLevel "process id fetch is successful" 1 "getProcessId"
else
 log $selectedLogLevel "process id fetched is blank" 1 "getProcessId"
fi

echo "$processId"

}
```

**output :** 2 PIDS

2. second case(processName as global variable i.e java))

   processName='java'

   getProcessId(){

   ```
    matchType=$1
    #defaulting matchArg to x i.e exact match
    matchArg=x

    if [[ $matchType == 'contains' ]];then
      matchArg=f
    elif [[ $matchType == 'exact' ]];then
      matchArg=x
    fi

    if processId=`pgrep -$matchArg $processName`
    then
     log $selectedLogLevel "process id fetch is successful" 1 "getProcessId"
    else
     log $selectedLogLevel "process id fetched is blank" 1 "getProcessId"
    fi

    echo "$processId"

    }
   ```

**output :** it returns only 1 PID which is execpted.

My requirement is pass process name from argument then it should return 1 PID only.
currently i am getting 2 PIDs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pgrep -f from shell script is returning 2 pid instead of 1](https://serverfault.com/questions/1150221/pgrep-f-from-shell-script-is-returning-2-pid-instead-of-1)

Answer (score 0):

We already answered this one here: [pgrep -f from shell script is returning 2 pid instead of 1](https://serverfault.com/questions/1150221/pgrep-f-from-shell-script-is-returning-2-pid-instead-of-1/1150222#1150222)

The second PID being returned is the PID of the process running the script. To make this work you have to modify the script so that it detects its own command line, and does not return that PID.

Comment: Then just comment it so we can close the question as a duplicate. No need to duplicate answers.

Comment: Noted, will do so in future.

Comment: "To make this work you have to modify the script so that it detects its own command line, and does not return that PID."  -> my question is  need help on this .. wat changes  i need to do in script so it return 1 PID only  in case 1

Comment: Probably best asked in one of the programming areas. It's really kind of off topic in ServerFault.